# Automatically source different setup.bash files when a starting singularity image

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

#### Problem description

I am trying to source the `setup.bash file` and other `setup.bash` files automatically when shelling into a singularity image. I, therefore, added the following line to my singularity recipe file:

```
%environment

    ## Source ros setup file ##
    . /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.sh
```

After building the singularity image this source command ends up in the `*90-enviroments.sh` script, which is then sourced when the singularity shell is opened. Unfortunately, the environmental variables that are supposed to be set when sourcing the `setup.bash file` are not available when I shell into the container using the `singularity shell --nv container.simg` command. For example, when I am trying to use the `roslaunch` command I get the following error:

`bash: roslaunch: command not found`

I found the following solution on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51037873/bash-script-to-perform-action-in-a-singularity-container-it-opens) but I was hoping there is something similar to the `runscript` argument that enables me to source files when shelling into a singularity container.

##### Version of Singularity:

3.0.3

##### Expected behavior

I expected the `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` file to be sourced when the container is loaded using `shell --nv container.simg`

##### Actual behavior

Although the source command ends up in the `*90-enviroments.sh` script none of the enviromental variables that are supposed to be added to my workspace when sourcing the `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` file is available in my workspace. These commands appear to be available again when I run the `bash` command inside the singularity image. I, therefore, suspect that the singularity image uses a slightly different /bin/bash shell. The `echo $SHELL` command both has `/bin/bash` as an output in both the singularity shell and the bash shell running inside the singularity image.

##### Steps to reproduce the behaviour

Add one of the following source commands to the `%enviroment` section of the singularity recipe file:

- `. /file_you_you_want_to_source.sh`
- `source /file_you_you_want_to_source.sh`
- `bash -c "source /file_you_you_want_to_source.sh"`
- `sh -c "source /file_you_you_want_to_source.sh"`
- `bash -c ". /file_you_you_want_to_source.sh"`
- `sh -c ". /file_you_you_want_to_source.sh"`

#### EDIT:

I migrated my issue to the [singularity Github issue page](https://github.com/sylabs/singularity/issues/3401)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321775/automatically-source-different-setup.bash-files-when-a-starting-singularity-image/) by [rickstaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/40372/rickstaa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2019-04-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-24**:
Two observations:

1. this reads more like a Singularity question than a ROS one
2. "none of these commands [..] work" is too vague: please provide accurate descriptions of what did or did not work and include error messages if you were presented any

**Comment by [rickstaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/40372/rickstaa/) on 2019-04-24**:
@gvdhoorn Thanks for your comment I updated the question and also migrated my question to the singularity GitHub issues page.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-24**:\

> migrated my question to the singularity GitHub issues page.

if you did, then please post a link to that issue here in a comment so we can keep things connected.

**Comment by [rickstaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/40372/rickstaa/) on 2019-04-24**:
This issue has been migrated to the [singularity GitHub issues page](https://github.com/sylabs/singularity/issues/3401)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-24**:
The official O(S)R(F) Docker images use `ENTRYPOINT` for this ([here](https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/blob/df67397a84d5df2406caca275486a50aa8d0b2aa/ros/indigo/ubuntu/trusty/ros-core/Dockerfile#L42) fi), with [this script](https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/blob/df67397a84d5df2406caca275486a50aa8d0b2aa/ros/indigo/ubuntu/trusty/ros-core/ros_entrypoint.sh).

The Singularity documentation discusses how `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` are converted / can be used in Singularity images and containers: [Singularity and Docker: Building images for Singularity from Docker Registries - Working with Definition Files - Directing Execution](https://www.sylabs.io/guides/3.0/user-guide/singularity_and_docker.html#directing-execution).

**Comment by [rickstaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/40372/rickstaa/) on 2019-04-24**:
@gvdhoorn Thanks a lot for pointing me to the right documentation. I now see I had a wrong understanding of when to use the `run`, `shell` and start commands. After thoroughly going to the documentation and testing out different options I came to the following conclusion on what to do in my case:

- Other than the option depicted by the StackOverflow question there is no easy method of directly sourcing files when invoking a container using the shell command.
- I think it is, therefore, a better idea to include a `%runscript` and `%startscript` in my recipe file and following interacting with the created container using the run and start instance commands. This gives me full control over whether I want to use the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` options supplied by the docker file or use my own run/startup commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As this question contains a singularity related issue it was discussed on the [github singularity issue page.](https://github.com/hpcng/singularity/issues/2833) The solution I created, based on comments made by @gvdhoorn and @jmstover, can be found below.

## Solution

Unfortunately as the singularity `%runscript` uses the `/bin/sh` you need a separate script to source a `setup.bash` file. I, therefore, in the `runscript` now open a `/bin/bash` shell using the `-rcfile` argument. Following in this rcfile called `.singularity_bashrc` I source the `setup.bash` files. In singularity versions >3.2.x you now also have the ability to directly do this from within the `runscript` by using a `shebang` line.

### Steps

1). Clone your .bashrc_file inside your singularity container.

```
### Clone .singularity_bashrc repository file ##
bash -c "cd / \
    && git clone https://github.com/rickstaa/pandasim_singularity_recipes \
    && cp /pandasim_singularity_recipes/.singularity_bashrc . \
    && rm -rf pandasim_singularity_recipes"
```

Alternatively, you can also add the following code to the `%post` section of your singularity recipe to create the .bashrc file from within your recipe file.

```
## Add extra commands to singularity entrypoint script
touch /.singularity_bashrc.sh
chmod +x /singularity_bashrc.sh
cat <<-EOF >> /singularity_bashrc.sh
    #!/bin/bash
    set -e
     
    # setup ros environment
    source "/opt/ros/\\\$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash"
    echo "Ros setup bash file sourced."
        
    # Setup Panda_simulation enviroment (chained to franka_ros and moveit)
    if [ -f "/pandasim_ws/devel/setup.bash" ]; then
        source "/pandasim_ws/devel/setup.bash"
        echo "Panda_simulation setup bash file sourced."
    fi
EOF
```

!!!!Use tabs instead of 4 spaces. More information on heredoc list indenting can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76481/cant-indent-heredoc-to-match-nestings-indent) !!!!

2). Add the following code in the `%runscript` section:

```
## Run custom entrypoint BASH script
OCI_ENTRYPOINT='"/custom_entrypoint.sh"'
OCI_CMD='"/bin/bash"'
SINGULARITY_OCI_RUN="${OCI_ENTRYPOINT} ${OCI_CMD} '-rcfile' '/.singularity_bashrc'"
eval ${SINGULARITY_OCI_RUN}
```

3). Build the singularity container using the following `build` command:

```
sudo singularity build --sandbox singularity_container singularity_recipe.def
```

4). Now you can call the singularity container using the singularity `run` command:

```
singularity run --nv singularity_container
```

---

Originally posted by [rickstaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/40372/rickstaa/) with karma: 111 on 2019-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0